# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator raises error NSSQLiteErrorDomain=26 when trying to access sqlite file

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nspersistentstore

Recently I added some concurrent accesses to my different domain models (which represent a subset of the persisted data). My crash reporting shows that I now stumbled upon some errors on iOS7,iOS8 & iOS9, that all seem to be based on

> NSSQLiteErrorDomain=26, NSUnderlyingException=File at path does not
>   appear to be a SQLite database
>   at the position I marked in the source code

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it and I can't really imagine that the sqlite file doesn't exist on some devices, since I ship it with my application bundle.

1. Is there a flaw in my code that prevents me from accessing the sqlite file?
2. Is there another possibility this error can occur from except a missing file?

Heres' my source code for the initialization of my model singleton and the `NSManagedObjectContext`

```
+ (id) sharedModel {
    static id sharedModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        sharedModel = [[self alloc] initWithStoreURL: kDefaultStoreURL];
    });
    return sharedModel;
}

- (id) initWithStoreURL:(NSURL *)storeURL {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // create managed object model
        NSURL * modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"MyApp" withExtension: @"momd"];
        NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: modelURL];
        // create persistent store coordinator
        NSError * error = nil;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
        if (![storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
            CLS_LOG(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
            // this is where the error occurs
            abort();
        }
        // init managedObjectContext
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:storeCoordinator];
        _mainContext = context;

        _someDomainModel1 = [[SomeDomainModel1 alloc] initWithContext:_mainContext];
        _someDomainModel2 = [[SomeDomainModel2 alloc] initWithContext:_mainContext];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`initWithStoreURL` may have an issue, but if you've been using this same code all along, maybe I am making an incorrect assumption.

You say that your SQLite store file is provided with the bundle, and if that's the case you need to open it readonly and in rollback mode.

```
NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{
    NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption:@YES,
    NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
```

Then, use the options when adding the store.

```
if (![storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                    configuration:nil
                                              URL:storeURL
                                          options:storeOptions
                                            error:&error]) {
}
```

Also, since you are seeing this, you should log a bunch more information (like the URL and the details of the error object).

However, you are calling abort(), so you should be able to get a stack trace and state information from the crash report as well.

The other thing... look at how you are generating your database.  You should make sure that you generate it in rollback mode (journal_mode=DELETE) as well.